# Usage of while(1){......} construct most frequently

Tags: perl

This is my code..

```
while (1) {
    do_stuff;
    do_some_checks;
    do {  warn error 1; last }  if not OK;

    do_more_stuff;
    do_some_checks;
    do {  warn error 2; last }  if not OK;

    do_even_more_stuff;
    do_some_checks;
    do {  warn error 3; last }  if not OK;

    ...
    #finally
    last;
}
```

I prefer it over the one below:

```
do_stuff;
do_some_checks;
if (!OK) {
    warn error 1;
} else {
    do_more_stuff;
    do_some_checks;
    if (!OK) {
        warn error 2;
    } else {
       do_even_more_stuff;
       do_some_checks;
       if (!OK) {
           ...
       }
       # finally
       success!    
    }
}
```

The only thing hits me every time will be, while using this construct sometimes I forgot to add the final `last`, resulting in an infinite loop. But this series-of-checks-and-early-bail pattern happens so often in my code that the construct quickly became second nature.

Anyone got the same habit, or perhaps using some alternative will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Woah, you are totally misusing a while there. While is for looping, you are not looping. I see what you want, but why not just use a sub?

```
##
# This sub does three things:
# thing1,
# thing2, 
# thing3
sub do_three_things {   
 do_stuff;   
 do_some_checks;  
 do {  warn error 1; return }  if not OK;  

 do_more_stuff;  
 do_some_checks;   
 do {  warn error 2; return }  if not OK;  

 do_even_more_stuff;  
 do_some_checks;
 do {  warn error 3; return }  if not OK; 

   ...
#finally   
 return; #if you forget this return, the sub will end anyway.
}

do_three_things(); # Call the sub
```

Advantages of the sub:

- Nicer code division
- Smaller scope

*Edit: as Hachi notes, you don't even need a sub, just a block works too for `last`. However, I myself prefer a sub so you can separate things more clearly, which allows easier testing and/or code reuse .*

Comment: +1 I use very often that construct myself (and I was about to post the same thing, too...)

Comment: you even don't need to use a sub; you can "last" out of a block two

Comment: @Hachi: good point! I prefer a sub, but just a block indeed does work too. Let me change that.

Comment: trying to loose this habbit ...hey thanks everyone all your points will be taken into consideration going further :)

Answer (score 4):

Erase the `while(1)`.

In Perl you can just "last" out of a normal block {} without a loop.

I had the same habit, until I learned how flexible perl is ;)

Comment: I disagree. A bare block is eminently readable. It says, here's a scope. No need to give it a name or control statement.

Comment: +1, I also find judicious use of bare blocks can improve readability, I also tend to add a `LABEL:` to the block and use `last LABLE;` to exit. To my mind the preceding label flags the block as having unusual flow control, so I know to look out for `last` and `redo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want goto, just use `goto`, don't disguise it as a loop construction.